# downloading xml from ftp in android

Tags: android, filesystems

I am downloading an xml file from ftp and using the following code to store :

```
FileOutputStream stream = openFileOutput("emp.xml", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

cd = ftp.retrieveFile("emp.xml", stream);
```

I want to read this file to parse in my application later.Previously i was using this code as i ahd stored it in res/xml folder :

```
XmlResourceParser parser = this.getResources().getXml(R.xml.employees);
```

How should i replace the above code to get emp.xml file.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`XmlPullParser`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). You can use a [`FileReader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileReader.html) or a [`FileInputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html) as the input for the parser.

You can take a look at the tutorial ["Parsing XML Data with XmlPullParser"](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/android-xml-adventure-parsing-xml-data-with-xmlpullparser/).